# Too many renders when useState setter function is set to an array inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Setting the state to a primitive value inside `useEffect` works fine, whereas setting it to an array/object causes multiple renders which I can't understand. I want to know what dependency is causing it to render multiple times. Can you please explain?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const UseEffectSetStateError = () => {

    const [arr, setArr] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

    useEffect(() => {

        setArr([4, 5, 6]) // this gives error
        // setArr(0)      // commenting above line and uncommenting this works fine 

    }, [arr])           

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
setArr(0)
```

the new `arr` state is `===` to the previous value in state (after the first effect hook runs). React detects this and skips re-rendering when all new state values are `===` to old state values, so further rendering doesn't occur, so the effect callback doesn't get called again.

In contrast, running

```
setArr([4, 5, 6])
```

always puts a *new* array into state. Every time the effect hook runs, you're creating a completely new array and putting it into state.

```js
console.log([1, 2] === [1, 2]);
```

They're not `===`, so React re-renders, causing an infinite loop.

Just for the sake of curiosity, if you did

```
const someArr = [4, 5, 6];
export const UseEffectSetStateError = () => {
  // ..
  useEffect(() => {
     setArr(someArr);
```

there would not be a re-render loop, because here, the new set array is `===` to the old set array; `someArr === someArr` in state, so re-rendering will be skipped after the second run of the effect callback.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @CertainPerformance. It works the way you said but the thing is, I am trying to generate the new array within the useEffect and then set that as new state. Not sure if there is a solution for that, but I can use a handler function (onClick) instead of useEffect until I find a better approach.

Comment: You can check to see if the new array contains the same elements as the old array. If it does, then return the old array inside the callback; otherwise, return the new array.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

useEffect(() => {

        const newItems = [2, 3, 4]

        if (JSON.stringify(arr) !== JSON.stringify(newItems)) {
            setArr(newItems);
        }

    }, [arr])

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s answer, why are you using 'arr' as a dependency at all. From the look of it, you're not trying to trigger the function everytime the value of arr changes right? You need to define a state variable that will tell your useEffect to run. I can provide a specific example if you can explain your use case better. But I would say use something like:

```
const [triggerUseEffect, setTriggerUseEffect] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    setArr([4,5,6])
}, [triggerUseEffect])
```

Inside the function that should trigger the useEffect, add this line:

```
setTriggerUseEffect(p => p+1);
```